How to find out where y intersects with x on the surface of a cycloid?
To find out where y intersects with x on the surface of the circle i use Math.sqrt(radius * radius - Math.pow( x, 2)) .
How do I find out where y intersects with x on the surface of a cycloid?
In the snippets bellow I have a circle and a cycloid. For the circle I am able to get the value of y from x with const y = Math.sqrt(radius * radius - Math.pow(radius - x, 2)). I want to be able to do the same for the cycloid and replace const y = 0 with a working solution.


(() => {
            const inputX = document.getElementById('xCircle')
            inputX.addEventListener('input', (e) => {

                const x = e.target.value

                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, radius, radius)
                drawCurve()
                drawIntersection(x)
            })

            const radius = 200

            const canvas = document.getElementById('circle')
            canvas.width = radius
            canvas.height = radius
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

            const drawCurve = () => {
                ctx.beginPath()
                ctx.arc(radius, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
                ctx.stroke()
            }
            drawCurve()

            const drawIntersection = (x) => {

                const y = Math.sqrt(radius * radius - Math.pow(radius - x, 2))                
               
               document.getElementById('yCircle').textContent = Math.round(y)

                ctx.beginPath()
                ctx.moveTo(x, radius)
                ctx.lineTo(x, y)
                ctx.lineTo(radius, y)
                ctx.stroke()
            }
            drawIntersection(inputX.value)

        })();


        (() => {

            const inputX = document.getElementById('xCycloid')
            inputX.addEventListener('input', (e) => {

                const x = e.target.value
                
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasW, canvasH)
                drawCurve()
                drawIntersection(x)
            })

            const radius = 100

            const canvas = document.getElementById('cycloid')
            const canvasW = radius * Math.PI, canvasH = radius * 2
            canvas.width = canvasW
            canvas.height = canvasH
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

            const drawCurve = () => {
                ctx.beginPath()
                for (let t = 0; t <= Math.PI; t += 0.01) {
                    const x = radius * (t - Math.sin(t))
                    const y = radius * (1 - Math.cos(t))

                    ctx.lineTo(x, y)
                }
                ctx.stroke()
            }
            drawCurve()

            const drawIntersection = (x) => {

                const y = 0
                
              document.getElementById('yCycloid').textContent = Math.round(y)

                ctx.beginPath()
                ctx.moveTo(x, canvasH)
                ctx.lineTo(x, y)
                ctx.lineTo(canvasW, y)
                ctx.stroke()
            }
            drawIntersection(inputX.value)

        })();
canvas {
            border: 1px solid
        }
<canvas id="circle"></canvas>
    <form>
        <label>x:<input id="xCircle" type="number" value="30"></label>
        y:<span id="yCircle"></span>
    </form>
    <br>
    <canvas id="cycloid"></canvas>
    <form>
        <label>x:<input id="xCycloid" type="number" value="40"></label>
        y:<span id="yCycloid"></span>
    </form>




it is just a case of sinus and cosinus mirroring...

You have to solve approximatively (numerically) the equation
t - Math.sin(t) == x/radius
to get t for x, then substitute t in y = radius * (1 - Math.cos(t)).
Solving the equation can only be done iteratively, here's a possible implementation based on Newton's method
let t = Math.PI/2; // initial solution (half value)
let converged = false;
for(let iter = 0; iter < 100; iter++){
    // tNext = Math.sin(t) + x/radius; // alternative, simpler fixed point iteration
    const tNext = t - (t - Math.sin(t) - x/radius)/(1 - Math.cos(t)); // Newton's method
    const delta = Math.abs(tNext - t);
    t = tNext;
    if(delta < 1e-8){
        converged = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!converged){
    throw new Error('No solution found');
}

const y = radius * (1- Math.cos(t));

Here's your snippet with that code inserted:


(() => {
            const inputX = document.getElementById('xCircle')
            inputX.addEventListener('input', (e) => {

                const x = e.target.value

                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, radius, radius)
                drawCurve()
                drawIntersection(x)
            })

            const radius = 200

            const canvas = document.getElementById('circle')
            canvas.width = radius
            canvas.height = radius
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

            const drawCurve = () => {
                ctx.beginPath()
                ctx.arc(radius, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
                ctx.stroke()
            }
            drawCurve()

            const drawIntersection = (x) => {

                const y = Math.sqrt(radius * radius - Math.pow(radius - x, 2))                
               
               document.getElementById('yCircle').textContent = Math.round(y)

                ctx.beginPath()
                ctx.moveTo(x, radius)
                ctx.lineTo(x, y)
                ctx.lineTo(radius, y)
                ctx.stroke()
            }
            drawIntersection(inputX.value)

        })();


        (() => {

            const inputX = document.getElementById('xCycloid')
            inputX.addEventListener('input', (e) => {

                const x = e.target.value
                
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasW, canvasH)
                drawCurve()
                drawIntersection(x)
            })

            const radius = 100

            const canvas = document.getElementById('cycloid')
            const canvasW = radius * Math.PI, canvasH = radius * 2
            canvas.width = canvasW
            canvas.height = canvasH
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

            const drawCurve = () => {
                ctx.beginPath()
                for (let t = 0; t <= Math.PI; t += 0.01) {
                    const x = radius * (t - Math.sin(t))
                    const y = radius * (1 - Math.cos(t))

                    ctx.lineTo(x, y)
                }
                ctx.stroke()
            }
            drawCurve()

            const drawIntersection = (x) => {
                let t = Math.PI/2; 
                let converged = false;
                for(let iter = 0; iter < 100; iter++){
                  
                  const tNext = t - (t - Math.sin(t) - x/radius)/(1 - Math.cos(t)); // Newton's method
                  // tNext = Math.sin(t) + x/radius; // simple fixed point iteration
                  const delta = Math.abs(tNext - t); 
                  t = tNext;
                  if(delta < 1e-8){
                      converged = true;
                      break;
                  }
                }
                if(!converged){
                  throw new Error('No solution found');
                }

                const y = radius * (1- Math.cos(t));
                
              document.getElementById('yCycloid').textContent = Math.round(y)

                ctx.beginPath()
                ctx.moveTo(x, canvasH)
                ctx.lineTo(x, y)
                ctx.lineTo(canvasW, y)
                ctx.stroke()
            }
            drawIntersection(inputX.value)

        })();
canvas {
            border: 1px solid
        }
<canvas id="circle"></canvas>
    <form>
        <label>x:<input id="xCircle" type="number" value="30"></label>
        y:<span id="yCircle"></span>
    </form>
    <br>
    <canvas id="cycloid"></canvas>
    <form>
        <label>x:<input id="xCycloid" type="number" value="40"></label>
        y:<span id="yCycloid"></span>
    </form>



